# May static and non static variables have the same name

Tags: java, variables, static

I have a class in that I need two variables one is a static one another one is Non-static.  What my problem is when we declaring two variables, can we declare them with same name?

Why I ask this question is the static variables and non-static variables are stored in two different areas (static variables in Method area and non-static(instance) variables in heap area).
So, what happens if I declare them with same name?  If it is wrong, what is the reason?

Comment: No, you cannot declare two member variables in the same class with the same name, no matter if one is static and the other is not. Java cannot know which of the two variables you mean if they have the same name.

Comment: You cannot declare two variables with the same name in the same scope (for example, in the same class). Q: Why would you want to try?  Just to be perverse?

Comment: No.  Variable name must be unique within each scope.  static vs non-static at the class level is not different scope.

Comment: @FoggyDay: Java lets you declare two different methods that have the same name but different argument lists.  Why _not_ two different variables that have the same name and different storage class?  At least one programming language that I can think of (ruby) lets you do that.  It works in ruby because the syntax for referencing a class variable is different from the syntax for referencing a member variable.

Comment: Yes, it's called "arity".

Comment: @SolomonSlow Java does have a formal way of referencing static variables: prepending the class name.  The reason it's not allowed is because since the beginning, Java has allowed unqualified class members to be referenced in instance scope; now allowing it would break old code. Eliminating switching costs associated with upgrading has been a sacred principle of Java, to the benefit of those who have investments in long forgotten code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you can't do the following:

```
public class X{
    int a;
    static int a = 10; //Illegal
    public X(int a){
        this.a = a;
    }
}
```

The reason is that both `a`s are in scope for an instance of x. For:

```
X x = new X(5); 
x.a; //were the static field with name a legal, this refers to both 5 and 10.
```

it is unclear which version of `a` is being referred to. Thus to prevent confusion it is illegal.

Answer (score -2):

You can have a variable inside of your method that has the same name as a class-scoped variable. In general, the variable in your method has priority over the class-scoped variable when the variable name is referred to from inside of that method. To be more clear in your code and to make sure you're accessing the correct one, use the **this** keyword to refer to the variable inside of the method and use the **super** keyword to refer to the class-scoped variable.